# how to add chinese_directory config to thinking-sphinx configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I am use thinking-sphinx 3.1.1, i have a modified sphinx version support chinese character search. it has a special config item must put in configuration
 chinese_dictionary: "/usr/local/sphinx-for-chinese/etc/xdict"

i have add "chinese_dictionay" to thinking_sphinx.yml 
this is my config:

thinking_sphinx.yml:

development:
  **chinese_dictionary: "/usr/local/sphinx-for-chinese/etc/xdict"**
  thread_stack: 1M

when i generate the configuration only thread_stack has in the developments.sphinx.conf, the chinese_directory has not.

I have search a argly solution, it must edit by hand. first generate the config, rake ts:configure , put the chinese_dictionary to developments.sphinx.conf by hand, then rake ts:index INDEX_ONLY=true, i do not like this way.

I think it can modify the thinking-sphinx gems by add a file to rails initializers directory.  i have look the thking-sphinx gem, but i can not understand how to modify

import: the chinese_dictionary: "/usr/local/sphinx-for-chinese/etc/xdict" must under the index, this is right config:

```
index article_core
{
    type = plain
    path = ~Documents/Project/blog/db/sphinx/development/article_core
    docinfo = extern
    charset_type = utf-8
    source = article_core_0
    chinese_dictionary = /usr/local/sphinx-for-chinese/etc/xdict
}

index article
{
    type = distributed
    local = article_core
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant, but this should do the trick (put it in an initializer):

```
module ChineseDirectoryAccessor
  attr_accessor :chinese_dictionary
end

Riddle::Configuration::Index.include ChineseDirectoryAccessor
Riddle::Configuration::RealtimeIndex.include ChineseDirectoryAccessor

Riddle::Configuration::IndexSettings.module_eval do
  singleton_class.send :alias_method, :old_settings, :settings

  def self.settings
    old_settings + [:chinese_dictionary]
  end
end
```

It makes sure Riddle (which is used for Sphinx configuration) is aware of the new setting.